# awsebcli installation failed,i am using python 3.4, pip 8.1.2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

```
 pip install awsebcli
    Collecting awsebcli
    Using cached awsebcli-3.7.7.tar.gz
    Collecting pyyaml>=3.11 (from awsebcli)
    Using cached PyYAML-3.11.zip
    Collecting botocore>=1.0.1 (from awsebcli)
    Using cached botocore-1.4.40-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cement==2.8.2 (from awsebcli)
  Using cached cement-2.8.2.tar.gz
Collecting colorama==0.3.7 (from awsebcli)
  Using cached colorama-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pathspec==0.3.4 (from awsebcli)
  Using cached pathspec-0.3.4.tar.gz
Collecting setuptools>=20.0 (from awsebcli)
  Using cached setuptools-25.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting docopt<0.7,>=0.6.1 (from awsebcli)
  Using cached docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz
Collecting requests<=2.9.1,>=2.6.1 (from awsebcli)
  Using cached requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting texttable<0.9,>=0.8.1 (from awsebcli)
  Using cached texttable-0.8.4.tar.gz
Collecting websocket-client<1.0,>=0.11.0 (from awsebcli)
  Using cached websocket_client-0.37.0.tar.gz
Collecting docker-py<=1.7.2,>=1.1.0 (from awsebcli)
  Using cached docker-py-1.7.2.tar.gz
Collecting dockerpty<=0.4.1,>=0.3.2 (from awsebcli)
  Using cached dockerpty-0.4.1.tar.gz
Collecting semantic_version==2.5.0 (from awsebcli)
  Using cached semantic_version-2.5.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 (from botocore>=1.0.1->awsebcli)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 (from botocore>=1.0.1->awsebcli)
  Using cached jmespath-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting docutils>=0.10 (from botocore>=1.0.1->awsebcli)
  Using cached docutils-0.12-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in c:\python34\lib\site-packages (from websocket-client<1.0,>=0.11.0->awsebcli)
Installing collected packages: pyyaml, python-dateutil, jmespath, docutils, botocore, cement, colorama, pathspec, setuptools, docopt, requests, texttable, websocket-client, docker-py, dockerpty, semantic-version, awsebcli
  Running setup.py install for pyyaml ... error
```

**this is the first error**
        Complete output from command c:\python34\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\MADHAV~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uddplklq\pyyaml\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\MADHAV~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-gz9ygj2p-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build\lib.win32-3.4
        creating build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\composer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\constructor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\cyaml.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\dumper.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\emitter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\error.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\events.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\loader.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\nodes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\parser.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\reader.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\representer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\resolver.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\scanner.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\serializer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml\tokens.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        copying lib3\yaml__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.4\yaml
        running build_ext
        creating build\temp.win32-3.4
        creating build\temp.win32-3.4\Release
        checking if libyaml is compilable
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "", line 1, in 
          File "C:\Users\MADHAV~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uddplklq\pyyaml\setup.py", line 342, in 
            'test': test,
          File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
            dist.run_commands()
          File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
            self.run_command(cmd)
          File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
            return orig.install.run(self)
          File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 539, in run
            self.run_command('build')
          File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
            self.distribution.run_command(command)
          File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
            self.run_command(cmd_name)
          File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
            self.distribution.run_command(command)
          File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "C:\Users\MADHAV~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uddplklq\pyyaml\setup.py", line 169, in run
            _build_ext.run(self)
          File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
            self.build_extensions()
          File "C:\Users\MADHAV~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uddplklq\pyyaml\setup.py", line 211, in build_extensions
            with_ext = self.check_extension_availability(ext)
          File "C:\Users\MADHAV~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-uddplklq\pyyaml\setup.py", line 237, in check_extension_availability
            depends=ext.depends)
          File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 460, in compile
            self.initialize()
          File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize
            vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
          File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc9_support.py", line 52, in query_vcvarsall
            return unpatched['query_vcvarsall'](version, *args, **kwargs)
          File "c:\python34\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsall
            raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
        ValueError: ['path']

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Have you tried using python 2.7? I have installed (and currently use) awsebcli without a problem with 2.7